# MQTT headers with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-mqtt

I'm using MQTT with Spring Integration.

I would like to include a contentType header in the MQTT message.

I'm writing to the MQTT broker in this way:

```
  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow outgoingMqttMsgFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("outgoingMqttMsgChannel")
        .enrichHeaders(headers -> headers.header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC, mqttTopic))
        .enrichHeaders(headers -> headers.header(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "usp.msg", true))
        .handle(new MqttPahoMessageHandler(mqttBroker, UUID.randomUUID().toString())).get();
  }
```

When I see the MQTT messages in RabbitMQ I see this:

[image]

This is, it seems that content type header is not being included in the message (only `x-mqtt-dup` and `x-mqtt-publish-qos`).

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MQTT v3 has no concept of "headers"; those headers are just the rabbitmq MQTT plugin's mechanism to handle QOS.

You would need to embed the content type in the payload somehow.

Comment: But, what is this then...? https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.5.11/api/org/springframework/integration/mqtt/support/MqttHeaderMapper.html ?

Comment: More on Spring docs: Since the MQTT v5 protocol supports extra arbitrary properties in an MQTT message, the MqttHeaderMapper implementation has been introduced to map to/from headers on publish and receive operations. By default (via the * pattern) it maps all the received PUBLISH frame properties (including user properties). On the outbound side it maps this subset of headers for PUBLISH frame: contentType, mqtt_messageExpiryInterval, mqtt_responseTopic, mqtt_correlationData (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html)

Comment: You are using the v3 message handler; see `Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler`. I don't know if the RabbitMQ plugin supports v5. If not, try mosquito.

Comment: Right. RabbitMQ MQTT plugin does not support v5 yet: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/2554

Comment: I understanded that I have to update the handler from MqttPahoMessageHandler to Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler and change the broker to Mosquitto. Now I'm stuck with the dependencies in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536165/spring-integration-uncompatibility-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

MQTT does not have headers but properties, but they represent a similar concept.

MQTT properties are supported since version v5.

If you want to be able to map Spring Integration headers into MQTT properties you have to use `Mqttv5PahoMessageHandler`.

There is an example in https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html

Finally, take into account that since RabbitMQ does not support MQTT v5, it neither supports MQTT properties. Use Mosquitto instead.