# Spring integration uncompatibility with Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-mqtt

I have this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <paho.version>1.2.5</paho.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-jmx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mqtt</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client</artifactId>
            <version>${paho.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.integration.config.DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.registerErrorChannel(DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java:210)

The following method did not exist:

    'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.rootBeanDefinition(java.lang.Class, java.util.function.Supplier)'

The method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.15.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder: file:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.2.15.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder
```

I really couldn't figure out which combination of versions of spring boot parent and spring boot integration will make this work.

Thanks!

EDITED:

I change `pom.xml` to use version `2.3.12.RELEASE` of spring boot parent and I removed the version tag of `spring-integration-mqtt`, but I'm still having the same error.

I have the following dependency tree when I execute `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="org.springframework:spring-beans"`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ example-app ---
[INFO] com.example:example-app:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.15.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: You need to figure out what is causing this old spring jar `5.2.15.RELEASE` to be on the class path. Look at the maven dependency tree.

Comment: You don't need `spring-integration.version` variable. Rely on the version coming from Spring Boot dependency management. Try this command `./mvnw  dependency:tree -Dincludes="org.springframework:spring-beans"` to figure out that not compatible Spring Framework dependency.

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan. I edited the project and the question taking into account your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Boot version `2.3.x` is out of support for a while: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support.

Consider to choose the latest and rely on dependency management from Spring Boot by itself: don't use explicit versions for those dependencies which can borrow it from Spring Boot.

The `org.eclipse.paho.mqttv5.client` will not work with that old Spring Integration version anyway. You have to use at least Spring Boot `2.6.8` to pull Spring Integration `5.5.12`.

Comment: Using that Spring Boot parent version worked for me, thanks.